# User Form action in Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I got confused about something. How can i control the excel sheet via userform?
For example:

- Open user form by clicking form button on excel sheet
- Create new excel sheet by clicking the button in user form.

Do i need to write the required code in the "module" section of vba or the "userform" section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Create a new **Module**, and inside add a **Sub**, like the code below:

```
Public Sub Main()

' call a Use_ Form1
User_Form1.Show

End Sub
```

Second , in your Sheet, once adding a Button, you will get a message box to add Macro Name, Select ***Main***.  Now, once you click on your Sheet's Button, your ***Main*** module will run, and it will Call the `User_Form1.Show`.

Third, in your **User_Form**, add a button (in this example it's ***Btn_1***), once you click it, add the simple code below (just for testing purposes).

```
Private Sub Btn_1_Click()

' add a Sheet to this workbook, after the last one, and name it "Test"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Test"

End Sub
```

And that's an example how to connect between the 2 objects.